# How do I extend/implement Mongo.Collection in Meteor with Typescript?

Tags: meteor, typescript

It appears that `meteor/mongo.Mongo.Collection` is an interface (according to [these type declarations](https://github.com/meteor-typings/meteor)), and most of the [sample code](https://github.com/Hansoft/meteor-typescript-example/blob/master/lib/collections.ts) on the web shows how to extend that interface and then write code for methods in a separate block:

```
  export interface List {
    _id?: string;
    name?: string;
    incompleteCount?: number;
  }

  export interface CollectionLists extends Mongo.Collection<List> {
    defaultName(): string;
  }

  export var Lists = <CollectionLists>(new Mongo.Collection<List>('lists'));

  // Calculate a default name for a list in the form of 'List A'
  Lists.defaultName = function(): string {
    var nextLetter = 'A', nextName = 'List ' + nextLetter;
    while (Lists.findOne({name: nextName})) {
      // not going to be too smart here, can go past Z
      nextLetter = String.fromCharCode(nextLetter.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      nextName = 'List ' + nextLetter;
    }

    return nextName;
  };
```

Is there a way to rewrite this example with classes instead of this interface with separate code blocks for all the added methods?